# searching an element in xml ignoring case

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
                        if (temp.Element(any_string) == null)//marked
                        {
                            temp.Add(new XElement(node_arr[j]));
                        }
                        temp = temp.Element(any_string);
```

here i am searching for an exsting element in XML through Linq and if that element is not found (ie,it does not already exist ),it is being added.if i enter 'Guava' to be added and 'GUAva' exists then  'Guava' is being added to XML file.Now I have both 'Guava' and 'GUAva' in the same XML file which I do not desire.Kindly Help.

Comment: Side note: XML node and attribute names are case sensetive. Please consider putting text for case insensetive search as values, not node names.

Answer (score -1):

```
Temp.Elements().Where( x=> x.Name.ToUpper() == "FOO").FirstOrDefault();
```

Untested...